# Как запустить функцию при выборе одного из элементов списка? Но функция должна быть описана отдельно (за скобками)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пример кода выглядит вот так, но `.change(filter)` почему то на срабатывает, если ли возможность заставить функцию работать, не хотелось бы ее повторять, удлиняя код. сама функция должна срабатывать не только по выбору элемента выпадающего списка, но и при загрузке.

```
$('#edit-field-sitynoth-und, #edit-field-sitynoth').change(filter);
    function filter() {

        var SVal = $('#edit-field-sitynoth-und, #edit-field-sitynoth').val();
        var a = $('#edit-field-street [value=_none], #edit-field-street [value=All]');
        var b = $('#edit-field-streetdud [value=_none], #edit-field-streetdud [value=All]');
        var c = $('#edit-field-district1-und [value=_none], #edit-field-district1 [value=All]');

        if (SVal == 862) {
          //a.prop('selected', 'selected');
          b.prop('selected', 'selected');
          $('#edit-field-streetdud, #edit-field-streetdud-wrapper').removeClass('active');
          $('#edit-field-street, #edit-field-street-wrapper').addClass('active');
          $('#edit-field-district1, #edit-field-district1-wrapper').addClass('active');
        } else if (SVal == 861) {
          $('#edit-field-streetdud, #edit-field-streetdud-wrapper').addClass('active');
          $('#edit-field-street, #edit-field-street-wrapper').removeClass('active');
          $('#edit-field-district1, #edit-field-district1-wrapper').removeClass('active');
          //b.prop('selected', 'selected');
          a.prop('selected', 'selected');
          c.prop('selected', 'selected');
        } else if (SVal == '_none' || SVal == 'All') {
          $('#edit-field-streetdud, #edit-field-streetdud-wrapper').removeClass('active');
          $('#edit-field-street, #edit-field-street-wrapper').removeClass('active');
          $('#edit-field-district1, #edit-field-district1-wrapper').removeClass('active');
          b.prop('selected', 'selected');
          a.prop('selected', 'selected');
          c.prop('selected', 'selected');
        }

      }
```

Comment: было бы не плохо Html увидеть

Comment: а что это за поля `#edit-field-sitynoth-und, #edit-field-sitynoth` и почему вы их так выбираете, и почему вы не скинули разметку?

Comment: @Grundy как тебе красота и изящность сего кода)))

Comment: В приведенном на данный момент коде описанных в посте ошибок нет, [минимальный пример](https://jsfiddle.net/661cuxtu/) работает стабильно

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, ну если дублирование убрать, то нормально

Comment: это одни 2 выпадающих списка выводящихся на разных страницах, содержащие одинаковые значения но имеющие разные идентификаторы (система управления их так назвала) конечно я бы ограничился одним, и код сократился бы, решил вопрос: #edit-field-sitynoth-und, #edit-field-sitynoth эти поля нужно было ни в одну переменную запихнуть а задать для них две отдельные, ну и проверку проводить уже по двум переменным. Разметку я бы конечно мог показать но страницы разные а скрипт хотел сделать как можно более универсальным для разных страниц

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, в скрипте уже сейчас используются данные для двух страниц, поэтому он никак не похож на универсальный. html нужен чтобы соотнести ваши действия с разметкой и увидеть что именно вы делаете